# Why AlertDetails.class is showing error in Android Notification's Pending Intent?

Tags: java, android

I am little bit new in Android and I am learning about Android Notifications,
Actually I want to set the notification tap action and open my app when notification get clicked, I am referring it from Android Documentation,

So I am referring this code :

```
// Create an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlertDetails.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
```

And I am getting error in Second Parameter of Intent Constructor i.e. `AlertDetails.class`.

So how should I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, I got my answer... I just have to pass the `ActivityName.class` in second parameter of Intent Constructor same as a normal intent.

So corrected code for intent to open MainActivity after clicking on notification is :

```
// Create an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
```